# Select first time a MIN and a MAX value occured in records from yesterday

Tags: mysql

I have a table called 'measurement' holding id (pri_key), dt (timestamp) and usage as columns.
The min or max usage can occur multiple times. I want to select the first record where the min and max value of usage occurred yesterday.

What I have so far:

```
 SELECT dt, usage FROM measurement as a,
      (SELECT MIN(usage) as mini, MAX(usage) as maxi FROM measurement) as m
WHERE m.mini = a.usage OR m.maxi = a.usage AND
a.dt >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE(a.dt) < DATE(NOW());
```

This gives me:

```
+---------------------+-----------------+
| dt                  | usage           |
+---------------------+-----------------+
| 2017-01-10 01:11:01 |               6 |
| 2017-01-10 01:55:01 |               6 |
| 2017-01-10 02:19:01 |               6 |
| 2017-01-10 03:11:02 |               6 |
| 2017-01-10 04:57:01 |               6 |
| 2017-01-11 08:22:02 |               6 |
| 2017-01-11 13:42:02 |               6 |
| 2017-01-11 17:52:01 |            2609 |
| 2017-01-11 23:06:01 |               6 |
| 2017-01-12 03:29:02 |               6 |
| 2017-01-12 04:17:02 |               6 |
| 2017-01-12 05:39:01 |               6 |
+---------------------+-----------------+
```

Yesterday when I was busy on this project it would at least give me all records from the day before. Now it just gives me all my records with either the lowest value and highest value. Anyway, I tried to filter the first time value '6' occurred and value '2609' occurred by using:

```
SELECT dt, usage FROM measurement as b,
      (SELECT MIN(dt) as first, usage as us FROM measurement) as a,
           (SELECT MIN(usage) as mini, MAX(usage) as maxi FROM measurement) as m
where m.mini = a.us or m.maxi = a.us and
a.first >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE(a.first) < DATE(NOW());
```

However that gives me an empty set. I am looking for:

```
| 2017-01-11 08:22:02 |               6 |
| 2017-01-11 17:52:01 |            2609 |
```

Comment: @krishnpatel You don't need to delete your answer, just improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't perhaps the nicest solution, but one option would be to use a subquery to restrict to records having minimum/maximum usage from yesterday combined with ordering and `LIMIT 1` to obtain the earliest record in each case.

For the earliest minimum usage from yesterday:

```
SELECT a.dt,
       a.usage
FROM measurement a
WHERE a.dt BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE(NOW()) AND
      a.usage = (SELECT MIN(usage) FROM measurment
                 WHERE dt BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE(NOW()))
ORDER BY a.dt
LIMIT 1
```

And for the earliest maximum usage from yesterday:

```
SELECT a.dt,
       a.usage
FROM measurement a
WHERE a.dt BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE(NOW()) AND
      a.usage = (SELECT MAX(usage) FROM measurment
                 WHERE dt BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE(NOW()))
ORDER BY a.dt
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I thought the same but wondered if it could be done within one go and just return two rows. If not, your answer will definitely do!

Comment: @Arjan_IO You can `UNION` together the two queries I gave you.  If you need help with that, let me know.

Comment: Nice idea. I know how that works so I'm ok but thanks.